# Use injected dependency in jQuery event listener in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, scope

I'm using Bootstrap 4 modals in Angular 6 and I want to redirect the user to another route once the modal is closed. However, I'm getting a scoping issue when the modal is closed telling me that my injected router is undefined.

My code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any


@Component({
    selector: 'app-modal',
    templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        public router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $('#mymodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            router.navigate(['/']) //tells me that router is undefined
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It is generally a bad practice to use jQuery with Angular framework. Instead of using Bootstrap+jQuery, I would suggest you try ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap which are built for Angular and do not depend on jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` to have access to the `router` as an injected dependency and **arrow function syntax(`(e) => {}`)** to rescope it to the correct scope. Like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  $('#mymodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', (e) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  })
}
```

Comment: Tried that as well, gives me "this.router is undefined"

Comment: Please update your question with the latest code that you've tried.

Comment: Did you try with the above syntax (arrow function)? The above code will only work with arrow function, since that function will not have its own this. If you are going with the traditional anonymous function "function (e) { " you need to assign this to a custom var before the callback (as in suggestion below)

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` keyword like that in `Jquery`.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
var self = this;
    $('#mymodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        self.router.navigate(['/']);
    })
}
```